# How to IMPORTRANGE using a sheet name given by another cell?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Trying to import range from another spreadsheet, but with the specific sheet varied based on the value of another cell.

`=IMPORTRANGE("GoogleSheetsURL","Soccer_G!B9:E30")`

I would like the sheet name (`Soccer_G`) to be a variable based on the value of cell A2.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is concatenate the value in A2 with the string in `IMPORTRANGE()`'s second parameter,

`=IMPORTRANGE("URL", A2&"!B9:E30")`